# Ruby time run block that sleeps for x seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm learning Ruby and experiencing a hard time with `Time`. Here is the requirement from rspec that I need to pass:

```
it "takes about 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second" do
  elapsed_time = measure do
    sleep 1
  end
  elapsed_time.should be_within(0.1).of(1)
end
```

My code for `measure` is:

```
def measure
  start = Time.now
  elapse = Time.now - start
end
```

What am I missing? I couldn't I pass the block that sleeps 1 second. I tried to test and call the block:

```
a = Proc.new{puts "hello"}
sleep 1
measure

# => Unknown error
```

Comment: add a parameter to your method and yield it inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand Ruby's code blocks I'll suggest you to read [this blog post](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/an-introduction-to-code-blocks/).

As you can see by this example:

```
def my_ordinary_method()
  #do stuff
  yield #the instruction that calls the block
  #do more stuff
end

def the_caller()
  #do stuff
  my_ordinary_method() do
    puts "I am the block. The one everyone talks about!"
    puts "I am gentle, colorful and polite"
  end
end
```

taken from the link above.

Your code should look like this:

```
def measure
  start = Time.now
  yield if block_given?
  elapse = Time.now - start
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed calling `yield` inside your measure method:

```
def measure
  start = Time.now
  yield if block_given?
  elapse = Time.now - start
end
```